# styles.css is not being applied to only one page in react and node.js app

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

So i have a website built in react and uses node.js, all pages load correctly but one, it does not load the css correctly, i am not sure why.
Another interesting thing is that it is not present in the developer tools either, Firefox and Google.

The below in in my .html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
```

when i load my project on localhost, i get this error.

```
The stylesheet http://localhost:3001/product/styles.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
```

If anyone can help that would be great as I can't seem to figure out why.
Note: i removed comments from the beginning of my css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to include styles in ReactJS through `import` statement:

```
import './css/component.css';
```

[See a complete example here](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-build-a-jsx-live-compiler-as-a-react-component)

And also there is a React docs ["Adding a Stylesheet"](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/)

Comment: Thanks @StepUp this worked, i'd also like to add for anyone else who sees this, if you are using bootstrap, some values may not be passed over correctly, so double check that there is consistency in syntax. as this doesn't result in an error.

Comment: @Joshua I am glad that it helped to you!:)

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary as pointed out by StepUp. Therefore, you should probably use them with JavaScript `import` statement.
Where is your css located? The file name is correct?